# Loading model with EmberJS Router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm my app.js, I'm defining:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', {
        path: ':post_filename'
    });
});
```

And my post template is defined as:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
  {{model}}
</script>
```

And I'm linking to the post:

```
{{#linkTo 'post' filename}}{{filename}}{{/linkTo}}
```

When I click on the link, the file name is printed out as expected and my url is formatted as: `http://localhost:8000/#/post-filename`. Great. But if I reload that url (or just navigate to it without going through the link) `[object Object]` is printed out instead.

I think I'm missing a fundamental concept of how EmberJS works. I guess it's not just pulling the model out of the url? What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What happens when you navigate to `/#/post-filename/` directly**

Because you specified a dynamic segment in your `post` resource (`path: 'post_filename'`), the route expects a *model*, which you can specify with the return value of the model hook. By default, for a route named PostRoute, Ember will auto-generate a model hook like this:

```
model: function(params) {
  return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
}
```

which, in this case, I assume is not what you're looking for. Did you define a Post model? If not, you can override the `model` hook on your `PostRoute` to whatever you need it to be, e.g.:

```
model: function(params) {
  //instantiate your model manually (ajax call, load from fixture, whatever)
  return getMyModel(params.post_filename)
}
```

Note that the `params` argument is an object that has keys equal to the dynamic segments you specified in your route. By convention, if it's the `PostRoute`, you'll use `params.post_id` and `path: /post/:post_id`.

Take a look at the [routing guide on models](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

**So then, why is it working when you click the link directly?
(via `{{#linkTo 'post' filename}}`)**

You attempt to transition to the 'post' route, and the **argument** to linkTo (in this case, it's the `filename` variable inside `linkTo 'post' filename`) is **passed as the the model for the route** you're going to enter and the **model hook is skipped all together.** Ember assumes that since you're setting up the linkTo, you're going to supply the model.

See [linkTo helper documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Added this fixed my issue: `App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(params) {
  return params.post_filename;
 }
});`